# CSS Hover doesn't work in IE8

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-8, dotnetnuke

I have an DNN web site which use's the following code for the menu dropdown.

IE8 doesn't like it and the sub menu won't pull down.

```
.nav-collapse:not(.in) .nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You can duplicate this by going to http://dnnsample.azurewebsites.net in IE8. The About Us has a submenu. If you have IE11 you can press F12 > press ctrl+8 and change document mode to 8.

Anyone know an alternate method of making this work in IE8?

Comment: The `:not` CSS3 selector isn't supported in IE8 : http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: Browser support for `:not()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility

Comment: By the way, the F12 developer tools isn't the best for checking older IE's. Better are VM's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two CSS rules. The second one should override the first but only for elements with the `.in` class. It should have the same effect as your selector using `:not()`.

```
.nav-collapse .nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav-collapse.in .nav li:hover > ul {
    display: none; // or whatever display value you have as default
}
```

The reason your CSS isn't working is because `:not()`is only supported by IE9+. [See this MDN article for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

The `:not` CSS3 selector isn't supported in IE8.

Try to select your element with using `:not` and your hover will work just fine.

http://caniuse.com/css-sel3